# WCF Service calling WCF Service - Where to put client service reference?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking at implementing a WCF Service which will in turn call one (or perhaps more) external WCF Services (or at least, web services which I will call from code using WCF Service reference(s))

My solution is broken down into ServiceLayer, BusinessLogicLayer, DomainLayer, DtoObjects etc.

My Question is:
The logic around the client will all be in the BusinessLogicLayer - but if I put the ServiceReferences in there then I will also need to put the service configuration in the ServiceLayer - since this is where the originating call will be made.

Is that the correct thing to do?

Or:
Create the client in the ServiceLayer and pass it into the BLL.
Not sure I like this idea...but it DOES mean only one config.

Or:
Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at it as any code that calls a WCF service is a WCF client, even if that happens to be another bit of code that is itself hosted as a WCF service.  Because of this, you will need the client side configuration to be present and available wherever the call is being made.  I don't know if there is a good way to share configuration, or if it's even advisable... instead, I would opt for separate configuration files in each place.  There won't really be much duplication in that you've got service-side configuration in one place, and client side configuration in the other.

If you can use WCF Discovery (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx), it can reduce the amount of configuration you'll have to create.  Also, using interfaces and `ChannelFactory<T>` instead of ServiceReferences will give you a cleaner setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its not so much instantiating the client proxy to the service, more in which layer this is done.  I think its best to do this in the BLL, so that anything else can also call the external services in the same way - but that means duplicating the config sections in the BLL project AND the WCF project.